# Simple footers with only a page number

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm using a memoir template with page header defined.  In the appendix, I maximize the geometry to print a lot of tables with narrow margins.  I currently disable the memoir header with `\pagestyle{empty}` or `\pagestyle{plain}` which both remove the header but print no page number in the footer, as is the default with `\documentclass{article}`.

How can I enable a simple footer with the pagenumber in the middle on some pages, and on the right on some others (where the bottom table is in the middle)?

Answer (score 4):

Section 7.3 of the `memoir` manual describes how to make your own pagestyles. (Your description of the `plain` style as not having a page number doesn't seem to match `memoir`'s default, so maybe there is something else going on there.)  But here's example of how you can make a pagestyle with numbers on the right:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for sample text

% Define a new pagestyle called 'right'
\makepagestyle{right}
\makeevenfoot{right}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{right}{}{}{\thepage}

% Make a pagestyle called 'myplain', if 'plain' has already been redefined
\makepagestyle{myplain} 
\makeevenfoot{myplain}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeoddfoot{myplain}{}{\thepage}{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain} % or {myplain} if plain doesn't give what you want here
\chapter{A chapter}

\lipsum[1-10]
\pagestyle{right}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It's possible that the template you are using has redefined the `plain` pagestyle. If this is the case, then you can use the pagestyle `myplain` as defined above instead.

Comment: I've written an PTJ article about the memoir pagestyles, see http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen

Comment: @daleif Thank, Lars.  Is there anything you would change about my answer?

Comment: nope no need