# Creating Running Headers and Footers, but not on the First Page

Tags: header-footer

I want a header similar to Microsoft word that appears at the top of each page. However I do not want this on the first page. I would like to have the name of the project on the left, my name in the middle, and the date on the right.

1. What packages and commands will create a header as described above?
2. What approaches can I take to customize the header?

Comment: For packages see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/how-to-customize-headers-and-footers

Comment: or otherwise [Word-style headers in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31426)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use `fancyhdr` to facilitate making headers and footers.  If you want the first page to have no header or footer---without using any special packages---you can issue `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the first page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%% a garbage package you don't need except to create examples.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{This is my name}
\rhead{this is page \thepage}
\cfoot{center of the footer!}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image: header and footer]

Comment: I found that this also removes the page nuber from the first page. Any way to have the page nuber on the first page in the footer but not anything else that I choose to have in the footer?

Answer (score 46):

The most obvious package is [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr) which allows you to set up left, right and center adjusted headers and footers.

Your document ned to start with:

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

You can then format your header and footer with

```
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
```

Just leave them empty if you do not need any entry. you should check the `fancyhdr` manual for details on all possibilities with the package.

Comment: What if I don't want the horizontal line that comes with "fancy"?

Comment: You can set the \headrulewidth to zero.

Comment: Whats the exact command? \headrulewidth{set=0} ?

Comment: You should take a look at the `fancyhdr` documentation, it contains a lot of useful information. So `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`

Answer (score 22):

It depends which document class you are using.

If you are using document class `memoir` you please have a look to the question [simple footers with only a page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12241/simple-footers-with-only-a-page-number). Document class `memoir` has its own header and footer mechanismn.

If you are using KOMA-Script, for example `scrbook`, you should use the KOMA-Script package `scrpage2`.

If you are using the classical document classes, for example `book`, you can use `fancyhdr` or `scrpage2`.

Meanwhile KOMA-Script has changed and was updated. The package `scrpage2` has now changed to `scrlayer-scrpage` with more possibilites.  I changed the following MWE to use the new package `scrlayer-scrpage` (only the call of the package has to be changed) instead of the old version `scrpage2` (I only commented the call).

MWE for the usage of `scrpage2` or `scrlayer-scrpage` (just move the comment sign to change the loaded package...):

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=12pt  %
 ,english        % 
 ,headinclude    %
 ,headsepline    % line between head an document text
%,BCOR=12mm      % 
]{scrbook}       % twosided, A4 paper

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext} % provides blindtext with sectioning

%\usepackage{scrpage2}  % header and footer for KOMA-Script, old version
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}  % header and footer for KOMA-Script

\clearscrheadfoot                 % deletes header/footer
\pagestyle{scrheadings}           % use following definitions for header/footer
% definitions/configuration for the header
\rehead[]{This is my name}        % equal page, right position (inner) 
\lohead[]{This is my name}        % odd   page, left  position (inner) 
\lehead[]{this is page \pagemark} % equal page, left (outer) position
\rohead[]{this is page \pagemark}
% definitions/configuration for the footer
\cefoot[]{center of the footer!}  % equal page, center position
\cofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}     % odd   page, center position

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```