# Header and footer for every page

Tags: header-footer

I am writing my thesis and I have some problems to create headers and footers. I want to add a header for left side of the  each page and page number in the middle of the page as a footer.

I tried to use `\pagestyle{headings}` but I don't want page numbers right side of the page. Also instead of chapter name, I want to section name as a header.

I tried `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[l]{Headings}
\fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
```

However this only add header and footer on the chapter page. I try to add `\section{title}` at the left top of the each page's header and page numbers to center of the each pages footer.

Comment: Have you seen the related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87768/headers-and-footers

Comment: Which document class are you using?