# Header and footer not on 1st page?

Tags: header-footer

My header and footer do not appear on the first page. I hope they do. [The solution of a duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87769/31917) is **not** working for me. That is why I still decided to post my question. I will make the tile more informative once I have known the cause.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % hide the links
% For custom spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2} 
% For the symbols
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[alpine]{ifsym}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{
\Mundus\enspace \href{http://sites.google.com/site/}{http://sites.google.com/site/}
}
\rhead{
\MVAt\enspace \href{mailto:e@gmail.com}{e@gmail.com}
}
\cfoot{\thepage/2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\LARGE \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose}
\author{X}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle% prints the title block
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace{12pt}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make sure to reduce your code to the very minimum, e.g. the only package necessary to show your problem is `fancyhdr` (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/3225#3225).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\maketitle` defines the current page style as `plain`. Hence you have to define the `plain` page style.

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
\lhead{
\Mundus\enspace \href{http://sites.google.com/site/}{http://sites.google.com/site/}
}
\rhead{
\MVAt\enspace \href{mailto:e@gmail.com}{e@gmail.com}
}
\cfoot{\thepage/2}
}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % hide the links
% For custom spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
% For the symbols
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[alpine]{ifsym}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{
\Mundus\enspace \href{http://sites.google.com/site/}{http://sites.google.com/site/}
}
\rhead{
\MVAt\enspace \href{mailto:e@gmail.com}{e@gmail.com}
}
\cfoot{\thepage/2}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
\lhead{
\Mundus\enspace \href{http://sites.google.com/site/}{http://sites.google.com/site/}
}
\rhead{
\MVAt\enspace \href{mailto:e@gmail.com}{e@gmail.com}
}
\cfoot{\thepage/2}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\LARGE \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose}
\author{X}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle% prints the title block
  %\thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace{12pt}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. `\fancypagestyle{plain}` is a paradox, though. LOL

Comment: Why not just `\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy\makeatother`?

Comment: @Sveinung That is also a possibility. I wanted to show it in `fancyhdr` way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *same* headers and footers on the title page as on the other pages, a simple solution is redefine the `plain`-pagestyle to have the same content as the pagestyle you use in the rest of the document (*i.e.* `\pagestyle{fancy}).`You may use the the `\let`-command to do that.

```
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
```

Since it contains the `@`you have to enclose it in a `\makeatletter\makeatother` pair. You already have such a pair where you redefine the `@\maketitle`-command, so add the `\let` either at the beginning or end of that code:

```
\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name

\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy %% ---> change the headers and footer at the title-page

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\LARGE \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)
```