# Modifying the page number

Tags: article, fancy

[image]I'm using Overleaf, and using the below code I want to modify the position of the page number to the footer. I looked online to find that the  `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` is used usually, but in my case it is not working, any idea why?

```
[![\documentclass\[12pt\]{article}
\usepackage\[demo\]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{XXXXXXXXXXX}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{XXXXXX\,|\, \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}



\title{XXXXXXX}
\author{XXXXXX}
\date{Septembre 2013}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\centering
\includegraphics\[scale=0.75\]{logo.pdf}\\\[10ex\] \textbf{XXXXXXX}\\\[10ex\] 
\textbf{Date:}
\end{center}

\newpage
\end{document}][1]][1]
```

Comment: You need to reset `\cfoot{}` too... And often the first page of a document forces a different pagestyle, so you can use a `\thispagestyle{fancy}` or redefine `plain` if you use `\maketitle`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206775/header-and-footer-not-on-1st-page

Comment: PS you formatted your code as an image, and now all the square brackets are quoted... 

Comment: thank you so much, the problem was solved by setting cfoot{}