# how to print same footnote in top left corner on every page generated by LaTeX?

Tags: header-footer, footnotes

[image]

Here is the image shown above.

Comment: Please post a code example (MWE). Probably something like `\usepackage{fancyhdr}\fancyfoot[c]{footer}`.

Comment: You might get more results if you use the more adequated term of "[header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87768/64454)" (or footer) in your research. Footnotes are [something different](http://www.plagiarism.org/citing-sources/what-are-footnotes/).